# Lua middleclass. Are class functions guarenteed to be called in preference to mixin functions with the same name?

Tags: lua

I'm working on a project that uses the lua middleclass library. My experiments show that if a class includes a mixin that has a function with the same name as a class function, then calling that function on an instance of the class will call the **class** function, not the **mixin** function.

But I couldn't work out why by reading the middleclass code. Is the behaviour guaranteed, or dependent on some call or include order?

EDIT: added minimal code below. Can I rely on myFoo:show() displaying 'Foo'?

```
class = require('middleclass')

-- this is a middleclass mixin, not a class
Bar = {}
function Bar:show()
    print("Bar")
end


-- class Foo implements 'show', and includes 
-- the mixin which also implements 'show'
Foo = class('Foo')
Foo:include(Bar)    

function Foo:show()
    print("Foo")
end


-- class LittleFoo does not implement 'show', 
-- but includes the mixin which implements 'show'
LittleFoo = class('LittleFoo')
LittleFoo:include(Bar)              


-- program
myFoo = Foo:new()
myLittleFoo = LittleFoo:new()

myFoo:show()                -- prints 'Foo'
myLittleFoo:show()          -- prints 'Bar'
```

Comment: Do you include before creating instance? Can you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @LeszekMazur, yes mixin include is before the onbject instantiation. Minimal code added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected behavior, you inherit method show from parent `Bar`, but you have other implementation in your class. Is common standard in object programing.

It is not in middleclass code, when you do `Foo:include(Bar)` you have **copy** of method list (by references) from `Bar`, but when you implement method `Foo:show() ... end`, then you rewrite this method, but only for `Foo`, so in `Bar` you have old method, and when you inherit it to `myLittleFoo`, you inherit old version.